# Is there such a thing as a Docusign Sender group?

Tags: docusignapi

This is probably more of an Exchange setup question: our project has multiple customer consultants who will all be sending out documents. We will have the signed docs come back as attachments and the customer consultants will download these docs to then upload them into our document library system. My question is: if customer consultant A sends a doc out and goes away for a couple of weeks, can another customer consultant get the reply email so that they can upload the attached doc? I guess it would be necessary to have the cust consultant A use a bcc to a system mailbox that we would set up. Has anyone else setup their system for just such a case? This is pretty common. I'm just looking for ideas here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several ways to do that in DocuSign

You could use "shared documents" as discribe here : https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-shared-documents

or custody transfer : https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custody-transfer that let you transfer document custody only **On Complete** and not on all the inbox.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish shared docs or custody transfer thru a REST api call?

Comment: I think you can do that through https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Set%20Shared%20Access%20Information.htm?Highlight=Shared